# Как убрать первую колонку в DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="hashInfoForEachGPU" Grid.Column="1" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="HashRates" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Проблема в том, что в начале появляется неясная колонка (см. скрин ниже). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто то знает как ее убрать?

Answer (score 5):

Это не первая колонка (столбец) а заголовок для строки.

Его можно убрать с помощью установки в 0 свойства [`RowHeaderWidth`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.rowheaderwidth)

---

Альтернативный вариант подсказанный [Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) - установить пустой шаблон:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate />
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, добавил в ответ